# Where is Proctor Teagan's armory within the Prydwen dirigible airship?

Tags: fallout-4

I searched the Prydwen high and low but never located the armory or Proctor Teagan. I am level 17 now so maybe I need to be a higher level or maybe it requires a special key or code from a terminal that I did not find. I understand it has a lot of ammo and a nice weapon inside so I would love to be able to locate and access it.  Thanks if anyone knows the location and are able to provide details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's on the main deck, at the far end from the ladder entrance, past the power armor stations. It's the store.

Proctor Teagan is in the store, which has a cage around it. Taking anything will be stealing, which is difficult with the Proctor standing right there.

[image]

Comment: OK thanks DC-looks like it may not be good for my new standing with the Brotherhood  to steal 0) . So it is a store but he does not actually sell anything then without causing problems. How about a mini nuke in his face/ haha

Comment: @Greg He sells stuff. You just can't go in there and take the stuff without stealing.

Comment: gotcha - I found him with your help THKS- & I stripped my old amour, got the new one offered, then sold the old amour parts  to him & bought some stuff - sweet